# Real combination in Groovy

Tags: groovy, combinatorics

Is there method or some smart way that's easy to read to make a [combination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) of elements in Groovy? I'm aware of `Iterable#combinations` or `GroovyCollections#combinations` but it makes *Partial permutation with repetition* as I understand it so far. See example.

```
// Groovy combinations result
def e = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def result = [e, e].combinations()
assert [['a', 'a'], ['b', 'a'], ['c', 'a'], ['a', 'b'], ['b', 'b'], ['c', 'b'], ['a','c'], ['b', 'c'], ['c', 'c']] == result

// What I'm looking for
def e = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def result = ???
assert [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']] == result
```

> **Feel free to post alternate solutions.** I'm still looking for better readability (it's used in script for non-developers) and performance (w/o unnecessary iterations).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not so sure about the readability, but this should do the trick.

```
def e = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def result = [e, e].combinations().findAll { a, b ->
    a < b
}

assert [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']] == result
```

Note that if a element occur twice in the list its combinations will also occur twice. Add a '.unique()' at the end if they are unwanted

Comment: Thanks. Just one thing. You don't have to even test a != b cos this condition is included in a < b.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a more generalized approach that allows you to specify the "r" value for your nCr combinations. It does this by storing permutations in Sets, with the Sets providing the uniqueness:

```
// returns combinations of the input list of the provided size, r
List combinationsOf(List list, int r) {
    assert (0..<list.size()).contains(r) // validate input
    def combs = [] as Set
    list.eachPermutation {
        combs << it.subList(0, r).sort { a, b -> a <=> b }
    }
    combs as List
}

// the test scenario...
def e = ['a', 'b', 'c']
def result = combinationsOf(e, 2)
assert [['a', 'b'], ['a', 'c'], ['b', 'c']] == result
```